# htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given when submitting the for

Tags: php, laravel

I have this form elements that contains text, select and text which generates array of the received data. for eg: `{{ Form::text('email[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => trans('Email')]) }}` 
If I do not validate the data displays just fine. but when I submit with validation error is displayed.

```
<div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>Company Detail
      </h3>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('name', 'Name', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          {{ Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => trans('Name')]) }}
        </div>
        <!--col-lg-10-->
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('country_id', 'Country', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          {{ Form::select('country_id', $country, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
        </div>
        <!--col-lg-10-->
      </div>
      <!--form control-->
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('city_id', 'City', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          {{ Form::select('city_id', $city, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
        </div>
        <!--col-lg-10-->
      </div>
      <!--form control-->
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('companyType_id', 'Company Type', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          {{ Form::select('companyType_id', $companyType, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
        </div>
        <!--col-lg-10-->
      </div>
      <!--form control-->
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('companySubType_id', 'Company Sub Type', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          {{ Form::select('companySubType_id', $companySubType, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
        </div>
        <!--col-lg-10-->
      </div>
      <!--form control-->
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('description', 'Description', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          {{ Form::text('description', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => trans('Discription')]) }}
        </div>
        <!--col-lg-10-->
      </div>
      <!--form control-->
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('established_year', 'Established Year', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          {{ Form::selectYear('year', 1950, date('Y'), null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
        </div>
        <!--col-lg-10-->
      </div>
      <!--form control-->
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('location', 'Address', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          {{ Form::text('location', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => trans('Address')]) }}
        </div>
        <!--col-lg-10-->
      </div>
      <!--form control-->
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('number_of_employees', 'Number Of Employees', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          {{ Form::text('number_of_employees', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => trans('Number Of Employees')]) }}
        </div>
        <!--col-lg-10-->
      </div>
      <!--form control-->
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Other Detail
      </h3>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('email', 'Email', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          <div id="addEmailField">
            <p>{{ Form::text('email[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => trans('Email')]) }}
            </p>
          </div>
          <p>
            <input type="button" value="Add Email Field" onclick="addEmail();" class="btn btn-success" />
          </p>
        </div>
        <!--col-lg-10-->
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('phone_type', 'Phone', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          <div class="form-inline" id="addPhoneField">
            <p>
              {{ Form::select('phone_type[]', ['home'=>'Home', 'work'=>'Work', 'mobile'=>'Mobile', 'fax'=>'Fax'], null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
              {{ Form::text('phone_number[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => trans('Phone Number')]) }}
            </p>
          </div>
          <p>
            <input type="button" value="Add Phone Field" onclick="addPhone();" class="btn btn-success" />
          </p>
        </div>
        <!--col-lg-10-->
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('website_url', 'Website Url', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          <div id="addWebsiteField">
            <p>
              {{ Form::text('website_url[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => trans('Website Url')]) }}
            </p>
          </div>
          <p>
            <input type="button" value="Add Website Field" onclick="addWebsite();" class="btn btn-success" />
          </p>
        </div>
        <!--col-lg-10-->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2
      </h3>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('Sunday_open', 'Sunday Open', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          {{ Form::text('Sunday_open', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => trans('Sunday Open')]) }}
        </div>
        <!--col-lg-10-->
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('Sunday_close', 'Sunday Close', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          {{ Form::text('Sunday_close', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => trans('Sunday Close')]) }}
        </div>
        <!--col-lg-10-->
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('Monday_open', 'Monday Open', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          {{ Form::text('Monday_open', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => trans('Monday Open')]) }}
        </div>
        <!--col-lg-10-->
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('Monday_close', 'Monday Close', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          {{ Form::text('Monday_close', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => trans('Monday Close')]) }}
        </div>
        <!--col-lg-10-->
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('Tuesday_open', 'Tuesday Open', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          {{ Form::text('Tuesday_open', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => trans('Tuesday Open')]) }}
        </div>
        <!--col-lg-10-->
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('Tuesday_close', 'Tuesday Close', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          {{ Form::text('Tuesday_close', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => trans('Tuesday Close')]) }}
        </div>
        <!--col-lg-10-->
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('Wednesday_open', 'Wednesday Open', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          {{ Form::text('Wednesday_open', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => trans('Wednesday Open')]) }}
        </div>
        <!--col-lg-10-->
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('Wednesday_close', 'Wednesday Close', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          {{ Form::text('Wednesday_close', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => trans('Wednesday Close')]) }}
        </div>
        <!--col-lg-10-->
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('Thursday_open', 'Thursday Open', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          {{ Form::text('Thursday_open', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => trans('Thursday Open')]) }}
        </div>
        <!--col-lg-10-->
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('Thursday_close', 'Thursday Close', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          {{ Form::text('Thursday_close', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => trans('Thursday Close')]) }}
        </div>
        <!--col-lg-10-->
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('Friday_open', 'Friday Open', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          {{ Form::text('Friday_open', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => trans('Friday Open')]) }}
        </div>
        <!--col-lg-10-->
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('Friday_close', 'Friday Close', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          {{ Form::text('Friday_close', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => trans('Friday Close')]) }}
        </div>
        <!--col-lg-10-->
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('Saturday_open', 'Saturday Open', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          {{ Form::text('Saturday_open', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => trans('Saturday Open')]) }}
        </div>
        <!--col-lg-10-->
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('Saturday_close', 'Saturday Close', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          {{ Form::text('Saturday_close', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => trans('Saturday Close')]) }}
        </div>
        <!--col-lg-10-->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Branch
      </h3>
      <div id="addBranchField">
        <div class="form-group">
          {{ Form::label('location', 'Location', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) }}
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            {{ Form::text('location[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => trans('Location')]) }}
          </div>
          <!--col-lg-10-->
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          {{ Form::label('branch_description', 'Description', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) }}
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            {{ Form::text('branch_description[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => trans('Description')]) }}
          </div>
          <!--col-lg-10-->
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          {{ Form::label('long', 'Longitude', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) }}
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            {{ Form::text('long[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => trans('Longitude')]) }}
          </div>
          <!--col-lg-10-->
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          {{ Form::label('lat', 'Latitude', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) }}
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            {{ Form::text('lat[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => trans('Latitude')]) }}
          </div>
          <!--col-lg-10-->
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- addBranchField -->
      <p class="col-lg-offset-2">
        <input type="button" value="Add Branch Field" onclick="addBranchField();" class="btn btn-success" />
      </p>
    </div>
```

as you can see there are input that takes array of values. When I submit the form it displays error.
Also I have the rules for the form

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'companyName' => 'required',
    ]);
```

for now I am just printing the submitted value. `print_r($request->all());`

Comment: where `htmlentities()` function is used? i didn't see that code

Comment: I would suggest just use plain html and never use htmlentities for you forms. Like when you use vue.js. It's not compatible with vue.js...

Comment: This is a good example of when template engines like Blade actually makes the view _less_ readable. Just because you _can_ do something in a template engine, doesn't mean that you _have_ to.

Comment: ^ _less tracable_

Comment: thanks for the reply. I used plain html and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'email.*' => 'required',
]);
```

try to validate array type input data this way